# Is a differential equation linear if the maximal solutions constitute a vector space?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $x'= F(t, x)$, $F$ continuous, with the property of existence and uniqueness of solutions. Suppose that the maximal solutions are defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and constitute a vector space.

Is it true that this differential equation is linear? Meaning that $F$ has the form $F(t, x) = A(t)x$.

Comment: In particular you have that $ax’= aF(t,x) = F(t,ax)$. Does that help?

Comment: If I combine this with the fact that for solutions $x, y$ we have that $x + y$ is also a solution, and therefore $x'+ y' = F(t, x) + F(t, y) = F(t, x + y)$ have I established linearity and I'm done already?

Comment: You need existence to get that there are such solutions. I suggest you try to write up a complete answer, then we can give you some feedback.

Comment: Otherwise, it could be that, for example, only the constant zero function was a solution. This would still give you that the set of solutions is a vector space, but you learn nothing about $F$ as you can only test with the zero function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function such that for all $t_0\in \mathbb{R}, x_0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ the IVP

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x'(t) &= F(t,x(t)), \\ x(t_0)&=x_0,
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
admits a global (classical) solution $x:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore, we assume that that the set of maximal solutions forms a subvector space of $C^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^n)$. We wish to show that for any fixed $t_0\in \mathbb{R}$ exists a linear map $A(t_0): \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $F(t_0,y)=A(t_0)y$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $t_0\in \mathbb{R}, y_1, y_2\in \mathbb{R}^n$ arbitrary, but fixed and for $j\in \{1,2\}$ let $x_j$ a solution of
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x_j'(t) &= F(t,x_j(t)), t\in \mathbb{R},\\ x_j(t_0) &= y_j.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

We start by showing that $F(t_0, \cdot)$ is additive. As the space of global solutions is a vector space, we know that $x_1+x_2$ is again an element in the vector space and hence again a solution. Therefore, we know
\begin{align*}
F(t_0, y_1+y_2)&= F(t_0, x_1(t_0)+x_2(t_0))=(x_1+x_2)'(t_0) \\
&= x_1'(t_0) + x_2'(t_0)= F(t_0, x_1(t_0))+F(t_0, x_2(t_0)) \\
&= F(t_0, y_1) + F(t_0, y_2).
\end{align*}
As $y_1, y_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ were arbitrary, we get that $F(t_0, \cdot)$ is additive.

Next we show that $F(t_0, \cdot)$ is homogeneous. Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary. As the set of global solutions is a vector space, we know that $\lambda x_1$ is again an element in the vector space and therefore $\lambda x_1$ is again a global solution. Hence, we get

\begin{align*}
F(t_0, \lambda y_1) = F(t_0, \lambda x_1(t_0))= (\lambda x_1)'(t_0) = \lambda x_1'(t_0) = \lambda F(t_0, x_1(t_0))= \lambda F(t_0, y_1). 
\end{align*}
As $y_1\in \mathbb{R}^n$ was arbitrary, we get that $F(t_0, \cdot)$ is homogeneous.

Thus, we get that for every $t_0$ the map $F(t_0, \cdot)$ is linear. Thus, this yields the claim.

Note that I needed to assume that we can solve the initial value problem for any starting time $t_0$ for this proof to work, but we did not need any uniqueness of the solution (of course you get the uniqueness of the solution a posteriori as the Picard-Lindelöf theorem kicks in a soon as know the ODE is linear).